# $A$ and $B$ commute on a dense set but $e^{iA}$ and $e^{iB}$ do not

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be unbounded, symmetric operators on a Hilbert space $H$ with a common domain $D$. If $AB = BA$ on $D$, is it necessarily that case that $e^{iA}$ and $e^{iB}$ also commute? If $A$ and $B$ are bounded, then I know that this must be the case. However, I am not sure if the same must be true for unbounded operators. Does anyone have a proof or a counterexample?

Comment: No, it's not necessarily the case. Nelson produced some counterexamples which are discussed in Reed and Simon, vol 1, section VIII.5. There's an [nlab-page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unbounded+operator#nelsons_example_of_noncommuting_exponentials_31) outlining the idea (the discussion seems to follow Reed and Simon quite closely).

Comment: One would have to require $ A $ and $ B $ to be self-adjoint and not just symmetric in order for $ e^{i A} $ and $ e^{i B} $ to be defined.